# run a function synchronously in nodejs

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, synchronization

```js
arp.stdout.pipe(parse).pipe(filter).pipe(through(function(device) {
    this.queue(device.mac + '\n');
    device_d.push(device.mac);
}));
```

```js
function CreateList() {
    arp.stdout.pipe(parse).pipe(filter).pipe(through(function(device) {
        this.queue(device.mac + '\n');
        device_d.push(device.mac);
    }));
    setTimeout(function() {
        return device_d;
    }, 1000);
}
```

This code is not getting executed before returning. I'm always getting an empty array.
I'll get the response only if the

```
arp.stdout.pipe(parse).pipe(filter).pipe(through(function(device)
//{this.queue(device.mac + '\n');device_d.push(device.mac);})); runs synchronously.
```

Comment: What is it that you are asking exactly?

Comment: Is it a question or an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need setTimeout? return inside setTimeout isn't return for function CreateList(). It's return for function created inside setTimeout.

If you want use sync function you should use [deasync](https://github.com/abbr/deasync) or something like that.

Install deasync using `npm install deasync` and try this code, it should work.

```js
function CreateList() {
    // variable for blocking loop until return value is ready
    var ret = false;

    arp.stdout.pipe(parse).pipe(filter).pipe(through(function(device) {
        this.queue(device.mac + '\n');
        device_d.push(device.mac);
        ret = true; // return values is ready, stop waiting loop
    }));

    while(!ret){
         require('deasync').runLoopOnce();
    }

    return device_d;
}

console.log(CreateList());
```

However using blocking loops and generally sync functions isn't recommended in Node.js

Correct way would be to convert this function to async like this

```js
function CreateList(callback) {
    arp.stdout.pipe(parse).pipe(filter).pipe(through(function(device) {
        this.queue(device.mac + '\n');
        device_d.push(device.mac);
        callback(device_d);
    }));
}

CreateList(function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

**UPDATE:** I didn't realize I was blocking sync function with simple loop in my original answer. You should use deasync inside loop.